# How to set marginLeft and marginRight in react-native app which is responsive for all devices

Tags: ios, css, reactjs, react-native, stylesheet

I need to set marginRight and left for `UI layout butto`n. If I set the `MarginLeft` and right it is not responsive for all devices. I need to set dynamic for all devices in a single styling.

Kindly clarify how to write css for `ios` and `android` devices which is responsive for all devices

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called config.js and add the below code.

import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

```
const config = {
    deviceWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    deviceHeight: Dimensions.get('window').height
}

export default config
```

Then import this .js file to the file where you are going to styling.

import config from './config'

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {,
       paddingLeft: config.deviceWidth * 0.1,
       width : config.deviceWidth * 0.8
    }
});
```

This will align your label according to your device width. So this will responsive to every device.

Like this you can use paddingRight: `config.deviceWidth * 0.2` to align from right.

By changing the value of **x** (deviceWidth * **x**) you can set margin as you want.